# Grails 3.3.1 console giving 404

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a grails application using the angular profile with the console installed in my build.gradle

```
console "org.grails:grails-console"
```

and I am running the application in development mode:

```
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
```

When going to the http://localhost:8080/console and http://localhost:8080/static/console, the console doesn't show. Using the 
Chrome console, I see that a 404 error happens:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/static/console
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I have no custom interceptors that could interfere with the console and don't use spring security or another security framework.

How can I make the Grails console work on my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use web based console you need to add plugin:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.1.1'
```

[grails-console GitHub sources and docs](https://github.com/sheehan/grails-console)

Your dependency:

```
console "org.grails:grails-console"
```

is for Swing based console that will run after "grails console" command

Comment: Hey @Evgeny, thanks for your answer. I've installed the right plugin, but now have an error when trying to access the console:
'No signature of method: org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleController.createLink()' I tried disabling crsf protection and installing grails-plugin-gsp, without success. Do you know what's missing?

Comment: for grails > 3.3.0 you need "org.grails.plugins:gsp:3.3.0" instead of "grails-plugin-gsp"

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't solve my problem, I still have 'MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /consoleNo signature of method: org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleController.createLink() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[action:index, absolute:true]].'

Comment: Show full build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 5.2.4 the plugin is working fine with a little modification in build.gradle file.

Try

implementation 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.1.1'

instead of

compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.1.1'